# .Xap file is not generated in Sivlerlight Web Application

Tags: silverlight, silverlight-4.0, xap

I have two Applications - Silverlight + Web.. the thing is that in Web application .xap file is not generated during Build.. 
Is there anything i can solve this problem with?
Thanks

Answer (score 3):

Right click on the Web project and select Properties.  Navigate to the Silverlight Applications side tab on the properties page.  What do you see?